# Display either checkbox or radiobox based on a binding value in Silverlight (Windows Phone)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I want to display several options in a listbox (options are saved as a list of string, using data binding on listbox)

These options may either be displayed as radiobox or checkbox (based on a bool (or enum) value, using data binding).

I know how to display a list of strings as a series of radiobox (or checkbox) in listbox. But how can I write the xaml so that which one to use is based on a value?

Answer (score 1):

Create both the radiobuttons and checkboxes and then use a converter to control their visibility based on the bound boolean value.

You'll find an example of such a converter at http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/07/visibility-type-converter/